# Find the norm of S

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, functional-calculus

Given $C[0,2]$ with the the max-norm. Let $X= \{x\in C ([0,2]): x (1) =0\}$.
We define $S:X\to\mathbb{R}$
as $S(x)=\int_{0}^{2}x(t)dt$
. Compute $||S||$. I have already found that $||S||\leq2$, but I haven't come up with the way to prove $||S||\geq 2$. Are there any hints?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider continuous functions in $X$ that approximate $f\equiv 1$ pointwise except for $x=1.$

Comment: Well, if you didn't have the restriction $x(1)=0$, that would be obvious, right? You could just choose $x$ to be the constant function $1$. Since you have this restriction, try to change this function a bit, in a small neighborhood of the point $1$.

Comment: I think you might try considering a sequence of continuous functions with $x_n(1)=0$ whose integral approaches $2$. Consider a function which is one everywhere away from a small interval around $1$ and which in that interval goes linearly to zero and back up again. (Should look like a V in this interval).

Comment: I have thought of many functions, none of which works. Their norm didn't equal to 1 when i  based on ||S||=sup ||Sx||, ||x||=1. Am I wrong with something? please correct me.

Comment: @Benjamin it seems like a piecewise function with a small epsilon, doesn't it?

Comment: @Linda Their norm doesn't have to be equal to $2$. Supremum is not maximum. If for each $\epsilon>0$ you can find $x$ with $||x||=1$ and $|S(x)|>2-\epsilon$, this will prove that $||S||\geq 2$.

Comment: @Mark it's hard for me to find an appropriate function x because I couldn't manage with the interval around 1 as you mentioned above. I am sorry I am new to this, but I think it isn't simply a linear function, right?

Comment: @Linda You can take it piecewise linear. It is the constant function $1$ everywhere, except for a small neighborhood of $1$. Like Benjamin described above.

Comment: @Mark Thanks for your help.

Comment: I appreciate your support @Benjamin

Comment: Thanks very much @RyszardSzwarc

Comment: You welcome.One possibility, if don't want to fight with defining functions defined piecewise, could be $f_n(x)=|x-1|^{1/n}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought I would spell out in some more detail the point discussed in the comments by me and other contributors. We all more or less suggest the same thing.

The point is that you can't just choose $x(t) = 1$ for every $t$ since you have the additional constraint that $x(1)=0$. But you can see by sketching graphs that you could *almost* have a function which is $1$ everywhere, except for some small interval around $t=1$.

Remember that $$\|S\|_* = \sup_{\max x(t) =1}|Sx|.$$ You know that $$\|S\|_*\leq 2,$$ and it seems plausible that we actually have equality. Suppose for a contradiction that we did not have equality. Then there exists $\alpha<2$ such that $\alpha$ is an upper bound for the set $\{|Sx| : \max x(t) =1\}.$ If we call $\alpha = 2-\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$, it suffices to show that there exists $\tilde x\in X$ such that $$|S\tilde x|\geq 2-\epsilon.$$

For this, I suggested choosing the function $$\tilde x(t) = \begin{cases}-\frac{2}{\epsilon} t+\frac{2}{\epsilon} & \text{ if } 1-\frac\epsilon 2<t\leq 1\\
\frac 2\epsilon t-\frac 2\epsilon &\text{ if }1<t\leq 1+\frac\epsilon 2\\
1&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

[image: piecewise function]

See pictured with $\epsilon = 0.3$. Then the integral is $\int_0^2 \tilde x\, dt = 2- \frac 12 \epsilon >2-\epsilon.$ This leads us to a contradiction. Alternatively you could have chosen $\tilde x$ as Ryszard Szwarc suggested, as some function $\tilde x(t) = |t-1|^{1/n}$ where you would need to find some $n$ sufficiently large so that a similar estimate for the integral holds.

Comment: For $f_n(x)=|x-1|^{1/n}$ we have $$\int\limits_0^2f_n(x)\,dx =2\int\limits_0^1x^{1/n}\,dx ={2n\over n+1}=2-{2\over n+1}$$

Comment: Could we stop at $2-\frac{1}{2} \epsilon$ to show that $||S|| \geq 2- \frac{1}{2} \epsilon$ then take the limit of both side as $\epsilon$ approaches to $0$?. I think  $||S||$ does not depend on $\epsilon$ so we could conclude that $||S|| \geq 2 $ after taking the limit.

Comment: Well, you could take sequences as I suggested in my comment. Take $\epsilon=1/n$, then you can show that $\| S\| = 2$ by showing that the integral of $x_n(t)$ converges to $2$ as you let $n\to \infty$. This is basically the same as my argument above in a slightly different form.

Comment: Oh, now that you have edited your comment, I agree with what you are saying. Yes you could do that if you wish. :)

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks everyone.